# Deriving Data.Complex in Haskell

Tags: haskell, deriving

I have code that looks a little like the following:

```
import Data.Complex

data Foo = N Number
         | C ComplexNum

data Number = Int Integer
            | Real Float
            | Rational Rational
     deriving Show

data ComplexNum = con1 (Complex Integer)
                | con2 (Complex Float)
                | con3 (Complex Rational)
     deriving Show
```

But this seems like a bad way to do it. I would rather have

```
data Foo = N Number
         | C (Complex Number)
```

and construct a ComplexNumber with something similar to `ComplexNumber $ Real 0.0`.

The question is how to make `Complex Number` possible. Since all of the types in `Number` have corresponding `Complex` instances, can I just add `deriving Complex` to `Number`?

Comment: How do you expect to be able to add a `ComplexNum` of form `con2 (Complex Float)` to one of form `con3 (Complex Rational)`?

Comment: @Tom by providing those functions myself ("promoting"/converting types, etc) - Number includes all representations of numbers I want like Int, Integer, etc and I will instance fractional for Number and then provide my own complex class with `instance Fractional A => Fractional (Complex a)`. I was hoping someone would know how to do this using Data.Complex instead of my own.

Comment: @user3125280 Why? What would this loss of knowledge and control over type gain you?

Comment: @chunksOf50 haha that's what I would expect from a haskeller - it is for implementing a weakly typed language (which I'm using as a chance to learn haskell). All number representations have to be compatible for basic arithmetic. (I've solved it myself, so unless you know a better way, don't worry too much :))

Comment: @user3125280: OK so you have a write an `instance Complex Number` yourself with all these type conversions implemented by hand.  You can't expect the compiler to do that for you!

Comment: @TomEllis Well actually I can expect a standard library complex class to be able to derive from an instance of fractional (where I put the type conversions) - there is nothing unreasonable about that. Is that not possible?

Comment: (Sorry, I actually mean `instance Num Number`).  Anyway, it's rather unclear what you're trying to do.  You can form the datatype `Complex Number`.  That's fine.  It's just pairs of `Number`.  It won't have an automatic `Num` instance though unless you provide an instance `RealFloat` for `Number` (an instance which is unlikely to make sense in any case).

Comment: @TomEllis Exactly my point (although I used fractional instead of num). I think it's quite clear what I'm trying to do - make my ComplexNumber dependent on Number - and the answer is "You can't without making your own ComplexClass"

Comment: But you *can* do `data Foo = N Number | C (Complex Number)`.  I don't know what you mean by "ComplexClass", but I doubt you need that.  You *do* need a `Num` instance, but because you have all those type conversions to write by hand anyway, this hardly seems like an additional difficulty.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46124/discussion-between-user3125280-and-tom-ellis)

Answer (score 4):

The Haskell approach is to have different types for `Complex Float` and `Complex Int` rather than trying to unify them into one type. With type classes you can define all of these types at once:

```
data Complex a = C a a

instance Num a => Num (Complex a) where
  (C x y) + (C u v) = C (x+u) (y+v)
  (C x y) * (C u v) = C (x*u-y*v) (x*v+y*u)
  fromInteger n = C (fromInteger n) 0
  ...
```

This at once defines `Complex Int`, `Complex Double`, `Complex Rational`, etc. Indeed it even defines `Complex (Complex Int)`.

Note that this does not define how to add a `Complex Int` to a `Complex Double`. Addition (+) still has the type `(+) :: a -> a -> a` so you can only add a `Complex Int` to a `Complex Int` and a `Complex Double` to another `Complex Double`.

In order to add numbers of different types you have to explicitly convert them, e.g.:

```
addIntToComplex :: Int -> Complex Double -> Complex Double
addIntToComplex n z = z + fromIntegral n
```

Have a look at http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html section 10.3 for more useful conversion functions between Haskell's numeric type classes.

**Update:**

In response to your comments, I would suggest focusing more on the operations and less on the types.

For example, consider this definition:

```
onethird = 1 / 3
```

This represents the generic "1/3" value in all number classes:

```
import Data.Ratio

main = do
    putStrLn $ "as a Double: " ++ show (onethird :: Double)
    putStrLn $ "as a Complex Double: " ++ show (onethird :: Complex Double)
    putStrLn $ "as a Ratio Int: " ++ show (onethird :: Ratio Int)
    putStrLn $ "as a Complex (Ratio Int): " ++ show (onethird :: Complex (Ratio Int))
    ...
```

In a sense Haskell let's the "user" decide what numeric type the expression should be evaluated as.

Comment: I was using Data.Complex, sorry - and I made some mistakes in the code too, I'll update it.

Comment: So to elaborate the typeclass Data.Complex exists already and I would like to know if I could avoid writing out ComplexNum somehow. I guess it would most likely involve instancing Complex for number and adding the (+),etc functions. They need to be unified somewhat, and I would like to have complex numbers for any real numbers.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate the answer, but it's not really my question's answer -  I only wanted to know if I could use Complex class in Data.Complex. However, this typeclass doesn't have `instance Num a => Num (Complex a) where` (or fractional instead of num in my case) so I can't just instance num/ fractional for my Number type. So the real answer is just 'do it yourself'.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be legal Haskell code. You have three constructors of type `ComplexNum` all named `Complex`. Also, data types must begin with a capital letter, so `foo` isn't a valid type. It's hard to tell what you mean, but I'll take a stab:

If you have a type

```
data Complex a = (a,a)
```

you can keep your definition of `Number` and define `foo` as:

```
data Foo = N Number
         | C (Complex Number)
```

Comment: sorry my mistake, they had different constructors but types complex Integer, etc - from Data.Complex